# $(this).val() duplicating on load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `<select>` input stored in a Bootstrap model. When the user selects an option from the list, I will eventually have it set up so the value appears in a textarea on the page.

At the moment, if the user closes the modal and then reopens and selects something else, the selection duplicates. When I console log `$(this).val()`, I get the following:

First open and select dog, console shows:

"Dog"

Second open and select cat, console shows:

"Dog Cat Cat"

Third open and select rabbit, console shows:

"Dog Cat Cat Rabbit Rabbit Rabbit"

It should only add the chosen value to the text area and opened once. The code below is what I'm using to be able to get the duplicates to show in the console.

```js
$('#animal').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="animal" class="form-control">
  <option>Dog</option>
  <option>Cat</option>
  <option>Rabbit</option>
  <option>Fish</option>
</select>
```

It's like it somehow remembers the previous times the modal was opened and duplicates the new selection for each time.

This only seems to be a problem when it's in a bootstrap modal. If I have it on the page as is, it works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is not very clear. What is being duplicated? The items in the select list? The values in the text area? It would help if you include more code for us to see and inspect.

Comment: I've added some more clarification. At the moment I've got it just spitting out into the console.

Comment: We'll need a [mcve]

Comment: I've added both my select and current jquery I'm using

Comment: What does this give you?  `console.log($("[id=animal]").length)`  (for first/second/etc times you select).

Comment: 1 / 1, 1 / 1, 1, 1 - is what I get

Comment: I've updated your question to include a stack snippet of your code, and it doesn't replicate the behavior you're describing.

Comment: I think the problem is having it in a bootstrap model. You're correct in that it works outside of a modal.

Comment: Can you update the snippet to include the modal so that others can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Are you getting explicitly, specifically `"1,1"` or are you getting `"1" [newline] "1"`?     It's literally impossible for that console.log I gave you to output "1,1" from an integer output.  Which leads to the question of what you get with your own console.log - is it "Dog Cat" or "Dog[newline]Cat"?  ie is the console.log getting run multiple times? This would happen if you call the `$("#id").change` every time you open the modal.

Answer (score 0):

With your js if your html matches as follows it should work.

Note:all i am trying to help with is if you have some extra logic involved in your js,then at least you can for a while comment the same and try if its working with just without it

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    //jQuery('#mymodal').trigger('click');
    $('#animal').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <select id="animal" class="form-control">
  <option>Dog</option>
  <option>Cat</option>
  <option>Rabbit</option>
  <option>Fish</option>
</select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "It works" is not a valid answer for an SO question.  If it worked, then OP would not be asking why it doesn't work.  Use comments to try to find why it's not working, maybe a comment with a jsfiddle to demonstrate that it should work.

Comment: Added detailed snippet and just wrapped the js code in document ready. that can be observed in above snippet.

Comment: @SandeepModak What was the change that causes it to work correctly? Was it adding the document ready, or something to do with the HTML? It's not clear from your code or comments.

Comment: its just to compare the users code with the working one

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow should describe how you fixed broken code. This answer does not do that.

Comment: all i am trying to help with is if user has some extra logic involved in his js,then at least he /she can for a while comment the same and try if its working with just without it.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include that disclaimer.